# Custom-drawn UIView as UITableViewCell Image

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

We have a simple UITableView where we're using the default style since we just need a label and an image.  However, we need our image to be custom-drawn.

We of course can't insert a UIView with a custom drawRect implementation as UITableViewCell expects a UIImageView, not a UIView.

We also tried subclassing UIImageView and overriding its drawRect but UIImageView doesn't call drawRect as its expecting its image data to come from an actual image, not a drawing routine.

Is there perhaps a way I can create a custom-drawn image and use that as the source for a UIImageView, which I can then simply pass to the UITableViewCell?

In lieu of that, the two (nasty) workarounds I've come up with are either

1. Perform custom drawing on the background view in UITableViewCell, or
2. Add our custom-drawn UIView to the view hierarchy of UITableViewCell's ContentView, bypassing using the built-in image capabilities.

Am I missing an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to make use of the cell's image view to add your custom view? Just add your custom view as a subview to your cell.

Comment: Because using the built-in version automatically handles all the constraints and other framework-level features the default cells already have.  Asking your question is like asking 'Why provide predefined styles'?  I want to use the existing style. I just want a custom-drawn image.  Make sense?